# How to get awk to do regex on column variable

Tags: awk

I'm learning awk. Trying to do something useful with it by listing all hidden files in `ls`'s long format:

`alias llh="ls -la | awk '{ if ( $9 ~ /^\./ ) { print $0 }}'"`

This is resulting in an error, however:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: { if (  ~ /^\./ ) { print -bash }}
awk: cmd. line:1:         ^ syntax error
```

The `$9` isn't showing in the error output. Maybe because it's empty? So I tried:

`alias llh="ls -la | awk '{ if ( $9 && $9 ~ /^\./ ) { print $0 }}'"`

Still no luck.

Comment: Yeah, looks like I'm in bash quote hell (again). Ugh. The command works fine when run directly on the command line.

Comment: OK, had to escape the variables in awk even when I had the entire alias value surrounded in single quotes. Which confuses me. I've got a severe mental block when it comes to bash quoting.